# Process terminated by signal 6, core shows kind of loop in libc

Tags: linux, gdb, glibc, coredump, sigabrt

On analysis of the core of a process (terminated by signal 6), on LINUX, stack bt shows:

```
Core was generated by `/opt/namsam/pac_rrc_qx_e1/bin/rrcprb'.

Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.

#0  0x0000005555ffb004 in epoll_wait () from /lib64/libc.so.6

(gdb) bt

#0  0x0000005555ffb004 in epoll_wait () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000005555ffafe8 in __epoll_wait_nocancel () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000005555ffafe8 in __epoll_wait_nocancel () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x0000005555ffafe8 in __epoll_wait_nocancel () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000005555ffafe8 in __epoll_wait_nocancel () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#5  0x0000005555ffafe8 in __epoll_wait_nocancel () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#6  0x0000005555ffafe8 in __epoll_wait_nocancel () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#7  0x0000005555ffafe8 in __epoll_wait_nocancel () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

libc seems to have gone in some loop. Did something go wrong with the application `rrcprb` here? Can you help me debug this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Since `__epoll_wait_nocancel` does not call itself, it's pretty clear that the stack trace you've got is bogus. Most likely cause is incorrect unwind descriptors in your `libc.so.6`.

It's also somewhat unlikely that you actually crashed in `epoll_wait`. Try `thread apply all where`, and see if there is a "more interesting" stack trace / thread for you to look at.

Comment: i tried 't a a bt' at gdb and got a total of 11 threads, but none of them running 'rrcprb' [the application that crashed]: (gdb) t a a bt

Thread 11 (process 8086):
#0  0x0000005555cc35f0 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000005555c7ce14 in __get_timed_out_process (proc=0x5555cb62a0, selfc=0)
    at /build/home/IPALight-cruisesandbox/ipal-1006/IL1_RNC_FGW_1006/R_IL1_2.6.1.5/SS_ILLibgen/src/core/refreshhand.c:443
Cannot access memory at address 0xfffffffffffffff8
How can i post an attachment showing the entire result..? sry am new here.

Comment: *All* of your threads are "running 'rrcprb'" -- threads share their entire address space, and they are all part of a single process. The way to post your entire 'thread apply all where' is to edit your original question, and expand it to include all the additional info.